# How to access variable of parent movie clip in Action script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

How to access variable of parent movie clip in child movie clip in Action script 3.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same way you would access a variable of any object, using `parent` as the target object. Because the `parent` property is of type `DisplayObjectContainer`, you will need to cast it to `MovieClip` like so:

```
trace((parent as MovieClip).myvar);
```

The reason for the need to cast to `MovieClip` is that it is `dynamic`, meaning you won't get compile-time errors for attempting to access properties that the compiler doesn't know about.

Comment: here i got the onther way to access variable of child movie clip.

**var num:Number = MovieClip(this.parent).myvar;
trace(num);**

its working.

Comment: That's it. Though you don't need to use `this` in front of `parent`.